# Extract haven_labelled vector's label as a vector of strings

Tags: r, label, r-haven

I've got a `haven_labelled` vector, from which I want to extract its labels as a vector of strings:

```
library(haven)
vec <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), label = "Región", labels = c(`one` = 1, `two` = 2, `three` = 3), 
                 class = "haven_labelled")

vec

#   <Labelled double>: Región
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3

#Labels:
# value label
#     1   one
#     2   two
#     3 three
```

`attr(vec, "labels")` doesn't do what I want since it returns a named vector:

```
#  one   two three 
#    1     2     3
```

Desired output:

```
c("one", "two", "three")
```

I've visited a lot of documentation and can't get to a solution, so your help would be very much welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a `named` vector, so use `names` to extract the `names` of that vector

```
names(attr(vec, "labels"))
#[1] "one"   "two"   "three"
```

Comment: @akrun unrelated to the Q, but did you ever solve sub-setting list of dataframes with a vector of names ? where, the names appear as column names for some df and as rows in another dfs'. But, both these are part of the list of df;s ? If so, Can you point me to your sol or I can write one more Q

Comment: @user5249203  Ddid you meant `lapply(lst1, function(dat) dat[intersect(names(dat), vec1)])`  The rows part is not clear.  If you can post a new question with some example, it would be helpful

Comment: No. I upvoted on of your similar answer, and added a comment.